How to retrieve user's PAT to cast a vote
We have an app that acts like a layer in-between Azure Repos and the users. We are using a PAT of a service account, everything works properly except the voting, because we cannot vote on behalf of another user. Therefore we are investigating how to retrieve the specific user’s PAT.
I’ve tried generating a token with a powershell like: Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication (Not sure what type of token is this):

eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IktRMnRBY3JFN2xCYVZWR0JtYzVGb2JnZEpvNCIs…

Then I’m trying
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{ORGANIZATION}/_apis/tokens/pats?api-version=7.1-preview.1' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IktRMnRBY3JFN2xCYVZWR0JtYzVGb2JnZEpvNCIs...' \
  --data '{
  "displayName": "new_token",
  "scope": "vso.tokens",
  "validTo": "2024-12-01T23:46:23.319Z",
  "allOrgs": false
}

But the tokens I created belong to the service account, I think. Is it possible to retrieve a PAT for an specific user? or how would be the flow to get the user’s PAT and let them vote? Thank you very much.

As clarified in my answer below, it is not possible to use an user account to fetch/create PAT for another user account. There also is no such tool to allow doing this. Because of the security of PAT. @JorgeAnzola

It is not possible to use an account to create the PAT (Personal Access Token) for another account.
Each account can only create PAT for itself, even if the account is an organization administrator. It also cannot fetch the existing token value of another account using API or CLI.
If one account can create/fetch PAT for another account, the token will no longer become 'Personal', and it also might increase the risk of the token being leaked. So, it's not a good idea.

Understood. The personal part made it very clear and now it seems obvious. But is there another authentication method I could use? Maybe redirect my users to a Azure login in order to retrieve the token so I can cast a vote with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-reviewers/update-pull-request-reviewer?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

@JorgeAnzola, As far as I know, there is no such method. And I also does not hear Azure DevOps has or will provide such method.
